# Scaling webpage with browser window

Tags: html, css

I want the webpage's content to scale properly with the browser window. When I change the window size, the title moves to the left but the next and previous windows stay in the middle of the webpage instead of staying 
centred around the text.

Here is the code:

```
<div class="slideshow-container">

 <div class="mySlides">
 <div id="title">
`<p>______</p>`
 </div>
```

`<a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
<a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>`

*the css*

```
#title {
position: static;
top: 50%;
width: auto;
padding: 16px;
margin-top: -22px;
color: #D9BFFF;
font-family: Times;
font-size: 25px;
text-decoration: none;
}   

.prev, .next {
cursor: pointer;
position: absolute;
top: 250px;
width: auto;
padding: 16px;
margin-left: 450px;
margin-top: -22px;
color: #D9BFFF;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 18px;
transition: 0.6s ease;
border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
} 

.next {
margin-left: 850px;
border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

.prev:hover, .next:hover, .active {
color: pink;
}
```

Comment: Look at this link: http://learnlayout.com/position.html The reason is that they are having absolute position.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question, but you might want to look into [@media](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp). When you want a website that works on all devices and Bootstrap doesn't do what you want then @media is usually my next step.

Answer (score 0):

With these css commands you can change the css by any width:

```
//tablet

@media only screen and (max-width:767px){

.prev, .next {
top: 250px;
width: auto;
padding: 16px;
margin-left: 200px;

} 

}

//phone

@media only screen and (max-width:480px){

.prev, .next {
top: 250px;
width: auto;
padding: 16px;
margin-left: 100px;

} 

}
```

I don't know, which position you want, but there you can change the margin-left or padding or whatever

Answer (score 0):

One way to accomplish this is by using content zooming based on the browser window size. You can use viewport units, specifically, viewport width (vw), to grow and shrink your objects as the browser window width is changed. If you want the zooming to stop at a given maximum browser width you'll need to convert the vw units to pixels and freeze the scaling at that point. Otherwise the site will keep growing as the window widens.

For an example of this see my open source project [SFUMATO](https://sfumato.fynydd.com).

This framework does all the work for you, but the underpinnings of using vw and rem units are there if you want to manually code your own solution. Again, this is my project and it is free to use.